# What's the difference between copying a .hg folder and using clone?

Tags: mercurial

Say I need to create x repositories that can push and pull from a central repository. Is there a practical difference between cloning all those repositories compared to copying the .hg folder x times from the central repository to empty folders?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One difference I can think of is that a copy isn't an atomic operation:
you can't be certain the repo you are copying isn't being modified.

---

Edit: the [`hg clone` man page](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#clone) actually mentions:

> In some cases, you can clone repositories and the working directory using full hardlinks with

```
$ cp -al REPO REPOCLONE
```

> This is the fastest way to clone, but it is not always safe.
>
> - The operation is not atomic (making sure `REPO` is not modified during the operation is up to you)
> - and you have to make sure your editor breaks hardlinks (Emacs and most Linux Kernel tools do so).
> - Also, this is not compatible with certain extensions that place their metadata under the `.hg` directory, such as `mq`.

Answer (score 3):

Another minor difference - if you perform a copy both the original and new repository will have the same parent repository.  With a clone the new repository's parent will be the original.

i.e. in the [paths] section of your .hg/hgrc file.

**Original Repository (/repo/hg/original)**

```
[paths]
default = /repo/hg/parent
```

**Copied Repository**

```
[paths]
default = /repo/hg/parent
```

**Cloned Repository**

```
[paths]
default = /repo/hg/original
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is one difference. Clone will attempt to create a hard link if both repository are on the same filesystem.  (Unfortunately, this doesn't work on windows)

Comment: Actually, it does work on a recent-enough NTFS filesystem - I think NTFS 5 is required of the top of my head. Definitely works with Win7, pretty sure it works with Vista as well, but don't have it to test.